# Minimum cost edge in path between nodes (tree)

Tags: trees

I'm working on a problem and I've managed to design an efficient algorithm, but I'm stuck at the last part.

After some processing I'm left with a tree and I have to answer several queries of the form $(x,y)$, such that for each such query we have to print the minimum cost edge on the path from $x$  to $y$.

Now, this can be done by getting the smaller value between the shortest edge on the path from $x$ to $\text{lca}(x, y)$ and the shortest edge on the path from $y$ to $\text{lca}(x, y)$.

My question is, how do we actually get the min-cost edge on the path from say $x$ to  $\text{lca}(x, y)$  ? Do we just simply use a breadth first search? And wouldn't that actually beat the purpose of computing the lowest common ancestor?

Comment: Is the tree a rooted tree, so that each node has a well-defined parent node?

Comment: No, it's just a regular graph (data structure - wise).

Comment: 1. Do you have any upper bounds on the degree of each node?  Is it a binary tree (i.e., each node has degree 3)?  2. Do you have any guarantees on how "balanced" the tree is, i.e., that its depth (or diameter) is $O(\log n)$, where $n$ is the number of nodes, or at least is much smaller than $n$?  3. Do you need to handle online queries, or all queries given in advance (i.e., you receive all queries before you need to answer any of them)?

Comment: 4. I realize your tree is unrooted.  If dealing with rooted trees is easier, one technique you can always consider (if it's helpful) is to pick any node and treat it as the root, and then apply some algorithm for rooted trees.

Comment: 5. If there are a total of $n$ nodes, I suspect I can find an algorithm that answers each such query in $O(\log n)$ time, after a preprocessing step that takes $O(n \log n)$ time and uses $O(n \log n)$ space for the extra data computed by preprocessing.  Is that useful?  Should I write that up?  This is better than breadth-first search, which takes $O(n)$ time to answer each query, but might not be optimal.  I don't know if there's an algorithm that can answer such queries in $O(1)$ time, after a $O(n)$-time $O(n)$-space preprocessing step (like for LCAs).

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  The minimum cost edge would be found by examining the edges along the path from $x$ to $lca(x,y)$ and $y$ to $lca(x,y)$.  Is your question how to find those paths?  Would these not be known when you find the LCA?

Comment: Hello, @D.W., thank you so much for your effort and interest in the matter. I haven't been able to respond, as I went to sleep shortly after posting and today's been filled with schoool and work related matters. Would it help if I posted in an hour or so the text of the problem I'm working on? And to expand on the matter at hand, I can answer the queries whenever I choose to, I just have to print the right answers, their respective order being that of the queries. There's no guarantee as to the degree of the tree.

Comment: This tree is actually the Maximum Spanning Tree(I don't know if this is proper terminogy) of some input graph. By Max ST I mean the spanning tree of said graph that's created by maximizing the weights of the chosen edges.